# Checking for errors/exception while using await in ListenableFuture Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I am new to Kotlin, and while I am aware of the concept about ListenableFuture, and how we can add callbacks to it for checking for success or failure.
However, I am trying to use await (https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-guava/kotlinx.coroutines.guava/await.html) feature.

There is a library function I am calling and this is how it looks like:

```
@NonNull
ListenableFuture<Void> removeAsync(@NonNull String queryExpression,
        @NonNull SearchSpec searchSpec);

/**
 * @deprecated use {@link #removeAsync}
 *
 * @param queryExpression Query String to search.
 * @param searchSpec      Spec containing schemaTypes, namespaces and query expression
 *                        indicates how document will be removed. All specific about how to
 *                        scoring, ordering, snippeting and resulting will be ignored.
 * @return The pending result of performing this operation.
 */
@NonNull
@Deprecated
default ListenableFuture<Void> remove(@NonNull String queryExpression,
        @NonNull SearchSpec searchSpec) {
    return removeAsync(queryExpression, searchSpec);
}
```

Now, I am calling this function like this:

```
suspend fun removeDocs() {
    val removeQuery = SearchSpec.Builder().addFilterSchemas("MyDocument").build()
    appSearchSession.removeAsync("", removeQuery).await()
  }
```

Now, I don't understand how do I check for the success of this operation? What sort of error handling can I do in `removeDocs` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coroutines allow to execute asynchronous operations using classic sequential code. Then we don't have to use callbacks or check for some flags in order to handle exceptions. Exceptions are handled directly - by throwing them.

If `await()` didn't throw an exception, that means the operation succeeded:

```kotlin
appSearchSession.removeAsync("", removeQuery).await()
// if we get here, remove succeeded
```

If you have to react somehow to the failed operation, use `try...catch`:

```kotlin
try {
    appSearchSession.removeAsync("", removeQuery).await()
    // remove succeeded
catch (e: Throwable) {
    // remove failed
}
```